# What is the best way to get Docker container logs into Elasticsearch?

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch, logging

I've got a Go app running in a container, and it does a lot of logging:

```golang
log.Println("Something happened!")
```

Since I can ssh into the server it's running on I can do `docker logs -f [id]` to look at the `stderr` output, that's all fine.

But now I want the logs to go into Elasticsearch.

What's the best way to do that? I've been seeing so many complicated ways to do it.

One way was to use the GELF logging format and Logstash, but the only Go GELF formatter I can find is super old.

Or log to a file and use Filebeat. But would I not want to skip that file step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to set up fluentd with docker:

https://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/docker-logging

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/

And then make fluentd to push to elasticsearch:

https://docs.fluentd.org/output/elasticsearch